# Using realloc on a char * within an array alters data outside of that array

Tags: c, realloc

I'm observing some really weird behavior regarding realloc .... I was wondering if y'all could help me.

I have an array of dynamically allocated char *'s called "frags". I also have a char * called "combination" which points to some string literal that represents a new fragment. I want to replace one of the fragments within "frags" with the contents of "combination." The way my project is structured, I am sending the frags array, index of to-be-replaced frag, and combination string into a function. Within this function I have:

```
printf("combination before realloc: %s\n", combination);
char *newString = (char *) realloc(frags[firstIndex], strlen(combination) + 1);
assert(newString != NULL);
printf("combination after realloc: %s\n", combination);


strcpy(newString, combination);
frags[firstIndex] = newString;
```

Oddly, the printf's do not print the same thing. The first printf yields "hellol" which is correct, but the next printf yields jibberish - something like "{?`?p??". Thus, the problem resides in the call to realloc. And I honestly have no idea what's going on. It seems the very call to realloc has messed with combination somehow, but I thought that if that could possibly happen then it would return NULL?

Please help me :(

Edit: Adding code

```
bool findMaxOverlap(char *first, char *second, char **combination, int *roundMax) {
    // setup lng and shrt
    char *lng, *shrt;
    if (strlen(first) >= strlen(second)) { lng = first; shrt = second; }
    else { lng = second; shrt = first; }
    int shrtLen = strlen(shrt), lngLen = strlen(lng);

    // check if lng contains shrt
    if (strstr(lng, shrt) != NULL && shrtLen > *roundMax) {  
        *combination = lng;
        *roundMax = shrtLen;
        return true;
    }
    else // check if lng's tail ends contain part of shrt

    {                              
        int numChars = shrtLen - 1, max = 0, shrtOffset = 0, lngOffset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < shrtLen && numChars > *roundMax && numChars > max; i++) {
            numChars = shrtLen - 1 - i;
            for (int j = 0; j < lngLen; j++) {
                if (strncmp(shrt + i, lng + j, numChars) == 0) {
                    max = numChars;
                    shrtOffset = i;
                    lngOffset = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shrtOffset > lngOffset) {
            // short first
            char newFrag[lngLen + shrtOffset + 1];  
            strncpy(newFrag, shrt, shrtOffset);
            strcat(newFrag, lng + shrtOffset);
            *combination = newFrag;
            *roundMax = numChars;
            return true;
        } else {
            // lng first

            char newFrag[lngLen + (shrtLen - numChars) + 1];
            strcpy(newFrag, lng);
            strcat(newFrag, shrt + numChars);

            *combination = newFrag;
            printf("combination in findmax is: %s\n", *combination);
            *roundMax = numChars;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void mergeFrags(char *frags[], int index1, int index2, char *combination) {

    int firstIndex, secondIndex;
    if (index1 < index2) {
        firstIndex = index1;
        secondIndex = index2;
    } else {
        firstIndex = index2;
        secondIndex = index1;
    }

    char temp[strlen(combination) + 1];
    strcpy(temp, combination);

    char *newString = (char *) realloc(frags[firstIndex], strlen(combination) + 1);
    assert(newString != NULL);

    strcpy(newString, temp);
    frags[firstIndex] = newString;
    free(frags[secondIndex]);

}

char *reassemble(char *frags[], int numFrags) {

    if (numFrags > 1) {
        char *combination;
        int max, index1, index2, currNumFrags = numFrags;

        for (int currentRound = 0; currentRound < numFrags - 1; currentRound++) {
            max = index1 = index2 = 0, combination = NULL;

            for (int i = 0; i < currNumFrags; i++) {
                for (int j = i+1; j < currNumFrags; j++) {
                    //find max overlap of pair
                    if (findMaxOverlap(frags[i], frags[j], &combination, &max)) {
                        printf("round #: %d, combination: %s, max: %d\n", currentRound, combination, max);
                        index1 = i; index2 = j;
                    } 
                }
            }
            // merge 

            mergeFrags(frags, index1, index2, combination);
            currNumFrags--;
        }
    }


    return frags[0];
}
```

Comment: show all code involving frags.....It's NOT a bug in realloc(), it's a bug in your code...

Comment: i didn't mean to come off as saying it's a bug in realloc. I meant that i've narrowed the problem to my call to realloc.

Comment: It might also be interesting to dump the pointer values involved: `combination`, `frags[firstIndex]`, and `newstring`.  How is `combination` allocated?

Comment: combination is on the stack. It's simply a pointer that gets assigned various values through iterations. The call to this subsidiary function sends in the current value of combination. I'll look at the pointer values rn

Comment: are you sure that `frags[firstIndex]` was allocated with malloc?  and when you say that `combination` is on the stack, how did you allocation the space on the stack?  the issue is not where you're storing the pointer itself, the issue is where you're storing the characters.

Comment: Frags itself is on the stack. However, every element (string) inside frags was allocated with strdup which contains malloc. When it comes to allocating combination, it's simply an automatic variable in my central function which I'm passing around to the other functions.

Comment: I could continue to make guesses here, but it would be better if you posted enough code so that we can see what's going on.  This should include the code related to `combination`, since that's what's getting trashed.

Comment: It does not answer the question but you could just do free(frags[firstIndex]); frags[firstIndex] = strdup(combination); Try to run the code under Valgrind (if it is Linux).

Comment: alright i added my code. i omitted the boilerplate parts which read in fragments

Comment: It looks like you're invoking undefined behavior at various parts of your code. Several times you use pointers to places in the stack that are about to be reclaimed, making them useless when you decide to use them. You set `*combination` to `newFrags`, but `newFrags` is about to fall out of scope, so you can't use that pointer. That's just one problem.

Comment: I only looked quickly but `free(frags[secondIndex]);` seems to just free a string partway through your fragments list and you go on to keep using that fragment later

Comment: `*combination = newFrag;` is a bug, because `newFrag` is local to that code block and ceases to exist when the function returns. To fix this properly you will need to redesign your function's interface.

Comment: `strncpy(newFrag, shrt, shrtOffset);` is probably a bug too: `strncpy` does not null-terminate its buffer but you then go on to use `strcat` which expects a null-terminated string.  `strncpy` should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said (in the comments above) that you were using `strdup` to allocate the data in `combination`, but what you're really doing is setting `combination` to point to data that's on the stack.  After `findMaxOverlap` returns, you are now pointing at unallocated space on the stack, and this provides you with the undefined behavior you're seeing.  When `realloc` is called, the area in the stack is reused, and the value of `combination` looks like garbage.

Comment: thanks for your answer. does that mean since combination is set to point to some place on the stack, after the function returns it will still point to that place in the stack but that place does not persist with the correct info? so anything (the right thing or some random shit) can be at that location? Is this why i need to use the heap to allocate persistent data?

Comment: that's correct.  if you run this code in a debugger, you can open a memory window displaying the contents of `*combination` and you'll see that this is overwritten.